# C++ Templates queries

Tags: c++, templates, stl

HI,
I started learning C++ STL's
i am just trying some small programs.one of them is below:

```
inline int const& max (int const& a, int const& b) 
{
    return  a < b ? b : a;
}

template <typename T>
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return  a < b ? b : a;
}

int main()
{
    ::max(7, 42);         // calls the nontemplate for two ints
    ::max<>(7, 42);       // calls max<int> (by argument deduction)
    ::max('a', 42.7);     // calls the nontemplate for two ints
}
```

I have some basic questions!!

1. why is the scope resolution
       operator used here?
2. why/how is
       that calling ::max<>(7, 42) will
       assume that the parameter passed are

   integers?

Comment: One piece of advice: it's not really idiomatic to pass/return ints by const reference like that. Just do it by value: "int max(int a, int b)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) why is the scope resolution
>   operator used here?

Probably to differentiate the max declared here from the one in (for example) the std:: namespace.

> 2) why/how is that calling ::max<>(7, 42) will assume that the
>   parameter passed are integers?

It doesn't have to assume anything - integer literals have the type int.

And to answer the question you didn't ask:

```
 max('a', 42.7);
```

matches the non-template version because type conversions are not performed on templated parameters, but are performed on non-template ones.

Answer (score 3):

1. Presumably to avoid conflicts with std::max
2. It's not assuming that the parameters are integers, it sees that the parameters are integers. It then assumes that the template argument is `int` because the parameters are integers.

Comment: #1 doesn't matter unless he has `using namespace std;` or `using std::max;` somewhere, btw.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) what you possible mean is that why does it work - the template does not require integers, just any types on which the "<" operator is defined. An integer fulfills this so it is ok to pass it to the template method.